# iPhone Configuration Utility on OSX10.11?

Tags: iphone, configuration, utility

iPhone Configuration Utility 3.5 can't install on OSX10.11 anymore.
So where's the latest iPhone Configuration Utility?

Comment: Do you have working copy for iPhone Configuration Utility app for macOS?

Comment: @Ramis This one can't installed on latest os version.  why do you want it?

Comment: This tool was used to generate provisioning profiles. As example to generate profile for Network APN (Access Point Name).

Comment: @Ramis  sorry, I think when last time it's can't installed, then I removed it. for generate provisioning profiles, you can follow apple's site.